# Nodejs promises catch "hell" then using sequelize orm

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Currently I developing web app for nodejs using popular sequelize orm and typesciprt. Here is a example from my code

```
this.createNewGame(player.idPlayer).then((game) => {

    this.getBestScore(player.idPlayer).then((bestScore) => {
         defer.resolve({
             idGame: game.idGame,
             bestScore: bestScore
         });
    }).catch((error) => { defer.reject(error); });

}).catch((error) => { defer.reject(error); });
```

Here is one of the method

```
private getBestScore(idPlayer: number): Q.Promise<number> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<number>();

    GameModel.max<number>('score', { where: { 'idPlayer': idPlayer } }).then((result) => {
        defer.resolve(result);
    }).catch((error) => { defer.reject(error); });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

I use catch in every method implementation and also in every call to method. I would like to have only one catch block in my expressjs router. I tried code like this and it works just fine, here is example:

```
//code in GameService class ...
getData(): Q.Promise<number> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<number>();

    this.method1().then((result) => {
        defer.resolve(result);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}

private method1(): Q.Promise<number> {
    var defer = this.q.defer<number>();

    throw 'some error occurs here';

    return defer.promise;
}

//router call GameService
router.get('/error-test', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {

    gameService.getData().then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch((error) => { res.send(error); });
    //works fine, here I get my thrown error

});
```

But in my previous example I need to use catch blocks everywhere otherwise If I get Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError or any other Unhandled rejection, nodejs stops working. Why I can't use only one catch block in my expressjs router when using calls to db with sequalize, like in my first example?

Comment: Is this TypeScript? You should tag it accordingly. Maybe also change your code to normal JS, to remove one hoop to jump through for people who want to help. That being said, for example your `getBestScore` can (and should!) be simplified to a one-liner: `return Q( GameModel.max('score', {where: {idPlayer: idPlayer}}) );` probably even just `return  GameModel.max('score', {where: {idPlayer: idPlayer}});`. Your use of `Q.defer` appears to be completely superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize operations return promises, so there is no reason to put Q into the mix. This is equivalent

```
private getBestScore(idPlayer: number): Q.Promise<number> {
    return GameModel.max<number>('score', { where: { 'idPlayer': idPlayer } });
}
```

It doesn't return a `Q.Promise` (sequelize uses bluebird), but the implementations should be interoperable, since they are both 'thenables'.